# What shell is used by cron?

Tags: debian, cron

cron runs shell commands from crontabs.

But having just got caught out by the differences between zsh and bash, I'm now concerned that I don't know which shell cron uses to interpret crontab commands? Obviously the simple case where the cron entry just points to a script file is handled by the `#!/path/to/interpreter` on the first line, but what when you have something more complex in cron?

I looked in `/etc/cron*` and can't see anything that might allow this to be set or changed?

Comment: (oops elicited a rtfm. My bad, looked at `man crontab` but not `man 5 crontab`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put `SHELL=/bin/bash` in your `crontab` - you can also point to a `.bashrc` using `BASH_ENV="/root/.bashrc"`. That should get you going. I actually don't know what happens if you don't have `SHELL` defined, but adding it to `crontab` makes it easy to tell what is what.

Answer (score 23):

The [crontab(5)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab%205) manpage deals with your query by default it's `/bin/sh`

> Several    environment  variables are set up automatically by the cron(8)
>          daemon.  SHELL is set to /bin/sh, and LOGNAME and HOME are set from the
>          /etc/passwd  line  of the crontab?s owner.  HOME and SHELL may be over-
>          ridden by settings in the crontab; LOGNAME may not.

so adding

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

to the crontab file would change the shell accordingly.

Comment: The link did not work for me but the default shell is also mentioned here: https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab.
Or directly on a Linux distribution by typing `man 5 crontab`.